# asp.net page not scrolling

Tags: asp.net, scroll, modal-dialog

Here is my problem:

[image: validation]

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlMyAddressBook" runat="server" BackColor="White"  CssClass="roundcorner">
    TEST<table style="width: 100%;">
```

Do I need to explain that the page doesn't scroll to show the list of all the validation errors?
Its a panel being shown on a modal popup... I have tried setting the height property for the panel... no use...
Also, including this (required) Jquery function in the HTML causes the panel to move to a corner... I have removed it for now from my HTML...

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
```

C# code for the button opening the modal:

```
 protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "key", "launchModalV2();", true);
        //ClearTextBoxes();
        PopUpAddressInLightBox();


        mpeTest.Show();
        hdnfld.Value = "Edit";
    }
```

HTML

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit Address pb" OnClick="btnEdit_Click" CssClass="btn"  />
 <asp:Button ID="btnAddNew" runat="server" Text="Add New Address pb" OnClick="btnAddNew_Click" />
```

I am using these 2 buttons to call the modal....

```
.modalBackground
{
background-color: Black;
-filter: alpha(opacity=80);
-opacity: 0.6;
z-index: 10000;
 }
```

Comment: Can you post the code from where you are opening this Modal?

Comment: try setting the `overflow-y:auto` of the modal container div

Comment: of the modal container or the panel container div?? Because the validations are on the panel

Comment: From your screen shot it looks like your modal pop up to too tall. I suspect that the height for the popup is not set. Can you provide more info on `mpeTest`?

Comment: <act:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeTest" BehaviorID="mpeTest" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowModal" PopupControlID="pnlMyAddressBook" OkControlID="btnOk" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"> </act:ModalPopupExtender>
The modal background class is added in the post...

Comment: set a height on your panel

Answer (score 1):

In the css of your modal popup, set the width of the modalpop up, then set the overflow:auto. That will give you vertical scrollbar. Example:

```
.ModalPopupPanel
{
  height:700px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

So,when the content height exceed the 700px, the horizontal scrollbar will show up. The same is true for the horizontal scrollbar where you need to set the width of the modalpop.